# Source for specifik service stack release

Tags: servicestack

How do I get the source for a specifik stable release of servicestack from Github?
I'm trying to download and build the source for version 3.9.0.0 but I am having two sorts of problems.

1) There are no labels for the main service stack project so I can't figure out at what commit the 3.9.0.0 was built from.

2) Since Service Stack main project depends on ServiceStack.Text I also need to know against what version of ServiceStack.Text the ServiceStack 3.9.0.0 was built against.

If anyone wonders. The reason I ask this is because the later ServiceStack releases are not all backward compatible and a project I recently took over is throwing exceptions down in the ServiceStack.Text. And the version of ServiceStack.Text seems important since the version of ServiceStack and ServiceStack.Text I downloade, collided on build on extension.

The state I am at is that I got souce for what seems to be 3.9.4 and I managed to get hold of a nuget packet of ServiceStack.Text with version 3.9.0.0 that I could compile against (no source) and this actuallt killed of the trubbeling exception in ServiceStack.Text so that problem seems at least temporarely solved. At the next issue I'll probably be stuck again so I'd really like the source. (It is the point with open source after all right?)

Best regards, Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although older versions are not supported by ServiceStack, you could to go back through the [ServiceStack commit logs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commits) until you see a message that says **INCR to v3.9.x**.

One way to quickly browse releases is to look at changes to the [Properties/Assembly.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commits/master/src/ServiceStack/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs?page=1) file which changes when the version is incremented.

As ServiceStack is uses components from different sub projects, you will need to do the same for [ServiceStack.Text](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text), [ServiceStack.OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis) and [ServiceStack.Redis](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis) as well.

ServiceStack keeps the same version in-sync with the other components, so the v3.9.4 of ServiceStack uses a v3.9.4 of ServiceStack.Text, etc.